# What does producer.override.compression.type do in Kafka Connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have Kafka Connect running on my local machine with `CONNECT_CONNECTOR_CLIENT_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_POLICY=All` and the connector with `"producer.override.compression.type": "snappy"`. My understanding is that it will make the Debezium connector use Snappy compression on the JSON messages it generates. When I run the Kafka console consumer I am able to see the JSON payload.

Could someone please help me understand where the decompression happens and why I don't see gibberish in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does exactly what you say. It applies to all connectors that include that setting, not only Debezium, and works for any data format, not only JSON. If you want the setting to apply to all connectors on the same worker, then you put `producer.compression.type` in the `connect-distributed.properties` file.

Producer batches are compressed over the wire and on the broker.

Consumers automatically decompress without any settings needed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It clarifies a lot of things. I have a follow up question. How do the consumers know that snappy was used?

Comment: It's in the record metadata @RuntimeTerror. In Kafka, every record can be compressed with a different method, and the consumer can still correctly decompress everything.